# How to perform alpha blending on saved raw argb videos(a image and a video will also work) using direct3d9 , direct3d10 or direct3d11?

Tags: directx11, directx9, directx10, alpha-blending

I'm trying to perform alpha blending on videos using direct3d11. I've wrote the code snippet below to achieve this. I've tried to read the video file out2.argb frame by frame and store it in the rawData. Later, I passed that rawData to CreateTexture2D but pTexture remained null after the execution of the API. So I tried passing NULL to the CreateTexture2D and passing rawData to the UpdateSubresource but again the pTexture remained NULL.

````
HRESULT result;
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    int size = 1280 * 720 * 4 ;
    void * rawData = NULL;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.Width = 1280;
    desc.Height = 720;
    desc.MipLevels = 0;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE| D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;


    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shader;
    shader.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    shader.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shader.Texture2D.MipLevels = -1 ;
    shader.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;


    fp = fopen("../Engine/Data/out2.argb", "rb");
    rawData = malloc(size);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    data.SysMemPitch = 1280 * 4;
    data.SysMemSlicePitch = 1280 * 720 * 4;


    if (NULL == rawData)
        return -1;
    int row_pitch = (1280 * 4) * sizeof(unsigned char);
    if (fp)
    {
        /*while (!feof(fp))
        {*/
            fread(rawData, size,1, fp);
            //D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA *sSubData = new D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA[1];
            //for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            //  sSubData[i].pSysMem = rawData;
            //  sSubData[i].SysMemPitch = (UINT)(1280 * 4);
            //  sSubData[i].SysMemSlicePitch = /*(UINT)(1280 * 720 * 4)*/0;
            //}

            //data.pSysMem = rawData;
            // GOT FRAME
            device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &pTexture);
            deviceContext->UpdateSubresource(pTexture, 0, NULL, rawData, row_pitch , 0);
            result = device->CreateShaderResourceView(pTexture, &shader, &m_texture);
            if (FAILED(result))
            {
                return false;
            }


    /*  }*/

        fclose(fp);
        fp = NULL;
        free(rawData);
        return true;
```
````

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_usage

> ### Resource Bind Options
>
> **Dynamic**: Input to a Stage: yes³
>
> 3 - The resource can only be created with a single subresource. The resource cannot be a texture array. The resource cannot be a mipmap chain.

---

Dynamic resources cannot be mipmap chains, so create your texture without mipmaps:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

---

You have two further problems with the above.

1. You're not filling in all members of the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC struct; you also need to initialize desc.SampleDesc.Quality to 0.
2. For a dynamic texture, you need to set desc.CPUAccessFlags.

So your final, working, D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC struct will look like this:

```
desc.Width = 1280;
desc.Height = 720;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

Comment: I have tried creating texture without mipmaps but again the pTexture is NULL only. It is not updating with the data of rawData.

Comment: @Chandana - updated with working version; I have tested and verified this in code, and it creates a non-NULL texture.